# Is it safe to edit NetworkManager.conf in this way

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

My University tells me that in order to use its VPN service I have to make changes to my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file with the following argumentation:

"When connecting to the VPN, new DNS server addresses will be provided to the client.  These should replace the ones normally used by it (which will be those of the local router or site from where it's connecting) so it can resolve names private to the University.
By default, Ubuntu Desktop will not use these due to to the way Network Manager works.  This can be corrected by disabling its DNS handling, following the steps below."

According to them my file should look similar to that

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Currently, my file looks like this

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Can somebody explain to me what all these things mean. As far as I can see I don't even have the `dns=dnsmasq` line and `#` is meant to comment out lines, right? So will that lead to any change?

Comment: I would be wary of any such instructions that don't state an OS version. My NM conf (16.04) has the "dsnmasq" line. But AFAIK it works  OK with my company VPN (ie. with a VPN to the company's network, I resolve company hostnames).

Comment: @xenoid The instructions are specifically for Ubuntu 16.04 and they say, of course, that it might be different on other versions. I am on 19.10 and my file doesn't even have the line.